# How to parallelize a while loop?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I am attempting to perform a value function iteration (for an [Aiyagari model](https://lectures.quantecon.org/py/aiyagari.html)). The loop I am hoping to optimize is here (EDITED TO INCLUDE MWE):

```
beta = 0.95
r =0.03
a_lb = -1.5
a_ub = 10
y_l = 0.9
y_h = 1.1
yGrid = [y_l, y_h]
aSz = 100
nstates = 2
V0 = np.zeros((nstates, aSz))
V1 = np.zeros((nstates, aSz))
aPol = np.zeros((nstates, aSz))
Tol = 0.0001
Iter_max = 300
err = 1.0
PI = np.matrix([[0.5, 0.5],[0.09, 0.91]])
aGrid = np.linspace(a_lb, a_ub, num = aSz)
#
#
#
Iter = 0
while (err> Tol) and (Iter < Iter_max):
    V0l= intp.interp1d(aGrid, V0[0,:])
    V0h= intp.interp1d(aGrid, V0[1,:])
    for a_today in range(aSz):
        for yix in range(nstates):

            def objective(a_tomorrow):                
                c = yGrid[yix] + (1+r)*aGrid[a_today] - a_tomorrow  

                exp_cont_Val = PI[yix,0] * V0l(a_tomorrow) + PI[yix,1] * V0h(a_tomorrow)
                return -(-1/c + beta* exp_cont_Val)

            minima_val = opt.fminbound(objective , a_lb, min(a_ub, yGrid[yix] + (1+r) *aGrid[a_today] -0.00001))
            aPol[yix, a_today] = minima_val
            V1[yix, a_today] = -objective(aPol[yix, a_today])


    err = (abs(V1-V0)).max()
    Iter = Iter+1
    V0=V1.copy()
print('Iteration ' + str( Iter) + ' with error ' + str( err))
```

This is a part of a much bigger loop that uses a bisection method to find a value for a variable `r`.
First I guess an arbitrary value for `r` and use it to fill the values in the `c` array. From my testing, this first part of the loop is very fast. For the second part (given above) I think the `opt.fminbound` has the most overhead. I tried to use `jit`, but I kept getting error messages, I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Which part do you want to parallelize? can you make it as a function

Comment: What `jit` are talking about?  Edit your tags if needed.  Indent's off?  What have you done to elminate one or more of the iteration levels?

Comment: You're going to have a bad time if you just try and wrap the current code in some tool from `multiprocessing` or `threading`. Basically every line in the loop body operates on some data structure that would be shared between workers, leading to unpredictable behavior. I'd focus first on refactoring to isolate the individual units of work, parallelize those, and them build them back up into the larger structures.

Comment: @wbadart I ended up doing what you suggested (or my best interpretation of it), by isolating chunks of the loop and passing the results of one section into the other. I basically just used 4 separate loops, and I that sped up my computation by a lot.

1: Can you suggest any material to look up so I can understand " refactoring to isolate the individual units of work, parallelize those, and them build them back up into the larger structures" better?

2: I don't think I technically 'solved' my problem, it just ended up going, away. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Hmm, that's tricky, since it's more of an intuition that you build up with practice than it is a concrete skill that can be taught. It's definitely important to understand the mechanics that underly different concurrency strategies, so I'd start by reading through the official documentation for [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). I'd keep the question open for reference (it hasn't been flagged yet so you're probably fine).

Comment: I'd be curious to see what I can do to refactor this code. OP, can you edit your post to be a full-reproducible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. show where `wage` and `zgrid` come from, fix indentation errors)?

Comment: @wbadart I'll edit the post on the weekend if that's ok? I am going to be out of town for a couple of days...